# Could Mac and Windows work on the same projects via GIT?

Tags: eclipse, windows, git, macos, projects

As title, there is any documented issue?
Because I am finding problems creating my local project using Eclipse on a Mac and getting everything from GIT.

Probably there might be a problem in the local Eclipse storage of the user-password but I was wondering if the different OS could create any kin of problems.
Thank you everyone.

Comment: Typically no as when you commit line endings are the only things changed, what specifically are you running into?

Comment: @AdamTuliper-MSFT Your comment is somehow confusing because of the title of this question.

Comment: @elab  My guess is that you are checking in your workspace.  The workspace is not shareable across platforms.  The .project, .classpath, source and other resource files are -- but do not check in other files.  Create a new workspace on every computer and then import from Git your project.

Comment: @AleksandrM - the idea was to get more information - as a cross platform git issue itself its something I rarely ever see :) as a messed up <something else> its more likely (like gitignore not using the correct files) - that's why I'm looking for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. If you have problems in eclipse with downloading the code from your git repository, as a temporary solution, you may

1. sync the code from terminal using the command `git clone <your_git_repo_url>`
2. import the code into eclipse (New -> import workspace) and continue coding
3. once done, you may commit (`git commit`) and push the changes from terminal using the command `git push`
4. In the other OS, run `git pull --rebase' to get the updated code. If you have changes in your local workspace, it will ask you to commit the changes and then run pull command.